# Can't optimize this complexed SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a pretty tricky SQL query that takes a long time due to the need to use AES_DECRYPT along with some other tricky circumstances. First, here is the query:

```
SELECT
CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ),
timestamp,
category,
status

FROM email_statuses

WHERE 

timestamp IN (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp)
    FROM email_statuses
    WHERE ( CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ?
        OR CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ? )
    AND category = 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_01'
)

OR

timestamp IN (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp)
    FROM email_statuses
    WHERE ( CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ?
        OR CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ? )
    AND category = 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_02'
) 

OR

timestamp IN (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp)
    FROM email_statuses
    WHERE ( CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ?
        OR CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ? )
    AND category = 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_03'
);
```

In each block where it says timestamp IN (... the first ? is the user's primary email and the second ? is the users secondary email.

Basically what this query does is return a list of the latest statuses for each of the 3 email's (category = the email's name). I only need the LATEST status for each for that user. So for example, a result for a query using "email@domain.com" may look like:

```
email---------------timestamp----------category-------------status---------  

email@domain.com----0000-00-00 etc-----EMAIL_TEMPLATE_01----Sent  
email@domain.com----0000-00-00 etc-----EMAIL_TEMPLATE_02----Open & click through  
email@domain.com----0000-00-00 etc-----EMAIL_TEMPLATE_03----Open
```

Since the email_status table is over 1000 records now, the query is taking up to 30 seconds since it needs to run convert/AES_DECRYPT on every encrypted email row in the status table. Any thoughts on ways to optimize this? I'm not much of a SQL pro.

Comment: Try running an EXPLAIN <sql> or EXPLAIN EXTENDED <sql> to see what the optimizer is doing and make sure that AES is the real culprit. You may find it's the ORs that are causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine all the `in` statements into a join:

```
SELECT distinct CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( es.email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ),
       es.timestamp, es.category, es.status
FROM email_statuses es join
     (select category, MAX(timestamp) as maxtimestamp
      from email_statuses
      where ( CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ? or
            CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ? ) and
            category in ('EMAIL_TEMPLATE_01', 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_02', 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_03')
      group by category
     ) csum
     on es.timestamp = csum.category
```

I've also included a `distinct` in case there is a match on more than one category.

Comment: should be "on es.timestamp = csum.timestamp AND es.category= csum.category"

Comment: @MarlinPierce . . . That would make sense to me, but I don't see that in the original question.  I specifically looked, and decided that the `distinct` comes closer to the original formulation.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick! (With Marlin's edit). Or I just added es.id and csum.id and compared those in the ON at the end. Not sure if that is much different.

Answer (score 2):

One optimization you could do would be to do the following:

1. first AES encrypt the parameters that supply the e-mail address
2. rewrite each query to test the actual values in the database table against the encrypted parameters

So, each query becomes something like:

```
// precompute the encrypted parameter (maybe on the PHP side, before executing the query)

SELECT MAX(timestamp)
FROM email_statuses
WHERE email = ?              -- here pass the already encrpyed paramter
    OR email = ?             --       .. same here
AND category = 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_02'
```

The basic idea is to avoid doing and `AES_ENCRYPT` or `AES_DECRYPT` on each test in the query. And rather to just encrypt the parameter, and test using that..

Comment: You are talking about doing something more along the lines of this right?
        WHERE ( email = AES_ENCRYPT( ?, '$key' )
        OR email = AES_ENCRYPT( ?, '$key' ) )

Comment: If so, I did just try that and I think it did improve the performance ever so slightly, but it is still taking a while for the query to run. Thanks for the validation!

Comment: well, yes.. something like that. But if possible it would be beneficial to even to the encryption once. and then just supply that as the parameter because the supplied parameter doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have three sub-queries, each has to decrypt all the records.  If you could do this in one sub-query, it should take a third the time.

```
SELECT CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ),
       timestamp, category, status
FROM email_statuses
WHERE 

timestamp IN (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp)
    FROM email_statuses
    WHERE ( CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ?
         OR CONVERT( AES_DECRYPT( email, '$key' ) USING UTF8 ) = ? )
        AND category IN ('EMAIL_TEMPLATE_01', 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_02', 'EMAIL_TEMPLATE_03')
    GROUP BY category
)
```

Comment: Would this return all three email template statuses for that user? I think I tried something similar but was pretty brain fried at the moment so maybe left out something crucial!

Comment: Gordon Lindoff beat me to it and had a cleaner answer.

Comment: Yes, the group by returns all three timestamps.  Likewise Gordon Lindoff's answer, but his also joins the category from the sub-query.

Comment: Note that I was considering a having category in (...) but that would be slower if there were other categories in the database.